# How to get all Firebase Firestore documents created by a list of users?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am building a soical media application using Firebase Firestore and React. I have a "posts" collection which stores post documents. In that post document, I store in a field the user ID of the creator of the post.

I also have a "users" collection which has user documents for authenticated users. In this user document I have a "friendList" array which is a list of user IDs.

I want to query for all posts created by the users in a "friendList" array and also listen for changes in the database.

I can get the querysnapshot for posts form a single user. But, I do not seem to find any solution for my problem.

Below is the code for my component where I need the posts:

```
export default function HomepageFeed({ friendList }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPostsFromFriends(friendList);
  }, []);

  async function getPostsFromFriends(friendList) {
    const promises = [];

    promises.push(getPosts(currentUser.uid));

    for (let i = 0; i < friendList.length; i++) {
      promises.push(getPosts(friendList[i]));
    }

    const postsForHomepageFeed = await Promise.all(promises);
    setPosts(postsForHomepageFeed);
  }

  function getPosts(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.collection('posts')
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .where('userId', '==', userId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          const data = snapshot.docs;
          if (data) resolve(data);
          else
            reject({
              error: `error getting posts from ${userId}`,
            });
        });
    });
  }

...render function here...
 <div className='feed_container'>
    {friendsPosts.map(({ id, post }) => {
        return (<Post
                key={id}
                id={id}
                ... /> )}  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to fetch that `friendList` array from user's document and make new requests for fetching posts from those users.

```js
const db = firebase.firestore()

const getUserFriends = async (userId) => {
  return (await db.collection("users").doc(userId).get()).data().friendList
}

const getFriendsPosts = async (friendUids) => {
  const postsCol = db.collection("posts")
  const requests = friendsUids.map(f => postsCol.where("userId", "==", f))
  const postsQSnaps = await Promise.all(requests)

  let posts = []

  postsQSnaps.forEach(qSnap => {
    posts = [...posts, ...qSnap.docs.map(p => ({ id: p.id, ...p.data() }))]
  })

  console.log(posts)
  return posts
}
```

Alternatively, you can [`in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) operator in query but if `friendList` array can contain more than 10 users, using `Promise.all()` as in the above code snippet might be easier.

Comment: I am getting an empty array with the solution above.

Comment: @anulamatamang can  you update your question with the latest code that you have ?

Comment: I can see the value of the state 'posts' sometimes randomly with my code (the one in the question) but after some time or with page reload or navigation to different component I do not have the data in the state.

Comment: @anulamatamang that seems to be a different issue with your framework's state management then. I'd recommend asking a new question by providing debugging details of the new issue.

Comment: If your original question has been answered, you can accept (✔) the answer.

Comment: I tried to accept the answer, but it won't let me saying I need 15 reputations.  In your solution above, is it sure that postsQSnaps always have the snapshots from individual requests from the requests array?

Comment: @anulamatamang `postsQSnaps` is an array of `querySnapshots`. Then each `querySnapshot` has document snapshots in them